# Accessing member of object set as exchange property in configure method of route

Tags: java, apache-camel, dsl

I have a router class in my camel context which uses Java DSL. I also have an object which is set as exchange property with name as 'details'. I want to access the value of member 'isLoaded' of this object. How can I do that. my router class is below:

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class DataLoader implements RoutesBuilder{


    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:fetchDetails").setBody(simple("select * from  details where loaded=<exhange.details.isLoaded>")).to("jdbc");
    }

}
```

Here what can replace `<exhange.details.isLoaded>` which will get the value of member of the object set as exchange property 'details'.

Comment: See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
public class DataLoader implements RoutesBuilder{


    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:fetchDetails").setBody(simple("select * from  details where loaded=${exchangeProperty.details.loaded}")).to("jdbc");
    }

}
```

This will work if the object in "details" has a property style getter `isLoaded()`. Refer to the [Simple](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html) language reference for more details.